# How to calculate compression ratio when using autoencoder in neural network

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

For example, if I use an autoencoder to compress a 1000 dimensional data set to 25 dimensions. Is the compression ratio is 40:1?

Other info:
The dataset contains 5000 samples.
2 million parameters are needed for the encoder.
Another 2 million parameters are needed for the decoder.

Does these numbers have something to do with the compression ratio calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the [compression ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression_ratio) is measured on the files. So the correct way of computing it is to calculate the size of you data **before** compression, run them through the AE, store them to your drive and then see how much size they occupy **after** compression.

Then simply divide the two:

$$
Compression \; Ratio = \frac{Uncompressed \; Size}{Compressed \; Size}
$$

Theoretically in your case this should give a 40:1 compression ratio, but, due to overhead and the way you store your data it might not be so high.